# C Socket recv()ing weird characters

Tags: c, windows, sockets

So i've stuck mainly to MAC/Linux with sockets and it all works fine so i've tried to somewhat of base my windows sockets off that maybe i am wrong for doing that and that's the whole issue, but the issue i am trying to fix right now is the console printing random characters after the actual string sent by the server.
Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>
#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)  
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

char message[4040];
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sock, newsock;
    int c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char smesg[155];
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Could not create socket! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //textcolor(2);
    printf("Socket Created!\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(3939);

    //bind
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Bind failed! Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    puts("Binded!");
    printf("\nNow Listening...\n");
    listen(sock, 1);
    //Accept!
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
    if (newsock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Couldn't Accept connection!");
    }
    printf("Accepted Connection!\n");
        //char *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
        //int client_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);
        while (1) {
            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(smesg, 4040, stdin);
            send(newsock, smesg, strlen(smesg), 0);
            bzero(smesg, sizeof(smesg));
            //memset(0, smesg, 4040);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)  
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int reader;
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[2000];
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Could not create socket! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //textcolor(2);
    printf("Socket Created!\n");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(3939);

    //Connect
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        puts("Connect Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected\n");
    while (1) {
        //memset(0, message, 4040);
        reader = recv(sock, message, 2000, 0);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", message);
        bzero(message, 2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I type "Hello" into the server console and the client console recv()s/Prints 
Due to the fact i can't C&P from console ill just have a picture of it instead
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jBMO.png)

Update to the question the null terminator as posted by many what i did to fix it was switch

```
        printf("Command: ");
        fgets(smesg, 155, stdin);
```

In server.c to

```
        bzero(smesg, sizeof(smesg));
        printf("Command: ");
        fgets(smesg, 155, stdin);
        strcat(smesg, "\0");
```

Comment: Cargo-cult 'bzero(message, 2000);' in the wrong place.

Comment: So, why is `memset(0, message, 4040);` commented out, why are you hard-coding a size of `4040` (which is wrong) instead of using `sizeof( message )`, and what happens the second time you type "Hello" ?

Comment: If i type hello again it just prints the same thing Hello and then abunch of those characters

Comment: 'send(newsock, smesg, strlen(smesg), 0);' does not even send the NUL terminator, and, as explained above, even if sent, (eg with 1+strlen), there is no guarantee that it will be received in the first recv call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really hard to tell exactly why you are experiencing this exact erratic behavior, because you are misusing several things at the same time, so really weird things can be happening as a result.

First of all, sockets are streams, they are not a message-passing mechanism.  This means that the sockets have no notion of a "message" that you are trying to send and receive. The socket at the receiving end has no clue whatsoever that you wrote 10 bytes at the sending end.  So, if you want to use sockets to send messages, then you have to implement a messaging protocol on top of the stream.

The simplest version of a messaging protocol on top of a stream protocol is to prefix each message with the length of the message.  So: on the sending end, first you write the length of the message to the socket, and then you write the message itself.  On the reading end, first you read the length, then the message.  The length is a fixed number of bytes, (usually 4,) so you always know exactly how many bytes to read/write.

Then, since sockets are streams, you have to pay attention to exactly how many bytes are read from the socket each time.  Just because you asked for 10 bytes it does not mean that you are going to receive 10 bytes.  If you ask for 10 bytes and you receive less than 10 bytes, then you have to repeat the call, to read more bytes.  The `recv()` function does not return any "reader". It returns the number of bytes that it successfully read. And it is not to be stored in a variable which is never examined afterwards.  It is to be taken into account so that you know whether you have received the entire message that you are expecting.

Also, do not forget the asciiz null-char terminators.  When you send a string, it is okay to consider the length of the message to be the `strlen()` of the string.  But when you receive that string, it will not be null-char terminated, so you cannot proceed to feed it to `printf()` without first appending a `\0` to it.  If you omit the null-char terminator, then `printf()` will print your string followed by whatever garbage happen to already be in your receiving buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Usual problem. You are ignoring the value returned by `recv()`:

```
reader = recv(sock, message, 2000, 0);
fprintf(stdout, "%s", message)
```

should be

```
reader = recv(sock, message, 2000, 0);
if (reader == -1)  // error
{
    perror("recv)"); // at least
    break; // out of the read loop and close the socket
}
else if (reader == 0) // EOS: peer has closed the connection
    break;
else
    fprintf(stdout, "%.*s", reader, message);
```